# How to solve ''"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}"?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I tried to use yolov5 on my raspberry pi for image detection. But whenever I tried using the raspberry pi camera this error message popped up with 'AssertionError: 1/1: 0... Failed to open 0'

I am using

ubuntu 22.04

Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB RAM)

Raspberry pi camera module v2
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like opencv has some problem to open your webcam. From the [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/realtime_rpi.html) on PyTorch's website, they have some configuration on "/boot/config.txt". Have you completed this step?

Another way to see which media devices available on your system, you can check with;

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```